# Filter without changing applied filters in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filtering

Here is my dataframe:

```
   Valeur ML Valeur MH - ML Valeur T90  Valeur T50  Valeur MH    OK/NOK      ref mel
0   6.04       25.15           160.0        98.0       31.19    Conforme    9966901.0
1   6.15       24.68           160.0        98.0       30.83    Conforme    9966901.0
2   5.54       24.47           160.0        98.0       30.01    Conforme    9966901.0
3   6.15       26.06           160.0        98.0       32.21    Conforme    9966901.0
4   6.07       25.19           160.0        98.0       31.26    Conforme    9966901.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
506 5.49       35.62           159.0        93.0       41.11    Conforme    49709944.0
507 5.75       34.71           158.0        94.0       40.46    Conforme    49709944.0
508 5.77       34.79           159.0        94.0       40.56    Conforme    49709944.0
509 5.56       34.28           159.0        94.0       39.84    Conforme    49709944.0
510 5.41       34.78           158.0        93.0       40.19    Conforme    49709944.0
511 rows × 7 columns
```

I used `df1.loc[df1['OK/NOK'] == 'Conforme']` to select data only if the condition is conforme.

Than I used another filter

`df1.loc[df1['ref mel'] == 19720904.0]`

to select only one type of product in the column ref mel. The output is

```
    Valeur ML   Valeur MH - ML  Valeur T90  Valeur T50  Valeur MH   OK/NOK    ref mel
66    3.05       35.23            167.0        132.0      38.28    Conforme   19720904.0
67    3.04       35.12            168.0        133.0      38.16    Conforme   19720904.0
68    3.03       33.70            168.0        135.0      36.73    Conforme   19720904.0
69    2.98       31.04            170.0        140.0      34.02  Non conforme 19720904.0
70    2.97       33.07            169.0        135.0      36.04    Conforme   19720904.0
... ... ... ... ... ... ... ...
450   2.86       30.35            170.0        140.0      33.21  Non conforme 19720904.0
451   2.68       30.73            169.0        137.0      33.41  Non conforme 19720904.0
```

As you can see the second filter cancelled the first one. I would like to keep the first filter applied and apply another filter on another column.

How can I filter out some data while preserving the previous filters and write these changes into CSV. I ask this how to write to CSV because when I used df1.to_csv() it writes the data to CSV without any of my manipulation on it.

Comment: `df1.loc[(df1['OK/NOK'] == 'Conforme') & (df1['ref mel'] == 19720904.0)]`

Comment: thanks man. I think this is new, because before when I applied the filters seperated like step by step, it was working like fine. Now I understand I should apply the filters in one line with   seperating them with '&'

Comment: And don't forget to use parentheses as `&` has a lower priority than `==` (or use `df1['OK/NOK'].eq('Conforme') & df1['ref mel'].eq(19720904)` that is less error prone).

Comment: Thanks ! concerning my 2nd question, how can I write this dataframe to csv without loosing my manipulation onit? As I wrote above to_csv() only writes the dataframe without manipulations I did

Comment: Operations are not in place: `df1[df1['OK/NOK'].eq('Conforme') & df1['ref mel'].eq(19720904)].to_csv('out.csv')`